# Implementing iAd Pop Ads In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I am trying to get a pop up ad when I go to a specific view. In the viewDidLoad I put this code but I am not getting an ad.

```
interstitialPresentationPolicy =
        ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy.Manual

    requestInterstitialAdPresentation()
```

My little banner ad at the bottom works but how could I get the pop up ad working?

Comment: May be that you need to request the ad once your view is on screen not just loaded, perhaps in viewDidAppear.  Just a guess..